# Curl_http_done: called premature

Tags: http, curl

I'm building a new service, and when I curl it I see a message Curl_http_done: called premature. I can't find any documentation on what it means and am wondering if my service is not conforming to some http spec?

```
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ curl localhost:6764/health -vv
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 6764 (#0)
> GET /health HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:6764
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-encoding: application/json
< content-length: 16
< connection: close
<
{"status":"ok"}
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: "Curl_http_done: called premature == 0" is just a debug message, it serves no purpose for ordinary humans, only to libcurl developers... (it will be removed in a future version)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Curl_http_done: called premature == 0` was just a debug message, it served no real purpose for ordinary humans, only to libcurl developers...

It was removed in [curl 7.53.0](https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_53_0) (released Feb 22 2017)

(The debug output told if the transfer ended "naturally" or if something made it it end before it was originally intended to. So the `premature` would be 1 on such errors and 0 if everything was fine.)